# How can I get the value from an action of the main view controller to the partial view?

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, viewbag

I have an MVC project with one view and inside this view I have a strongly partial view  which is of the type `IEnumerable<Raja.DomainClasses.Entities.InvoiceItem>`. Inside my partial view is a `Telerik MVC` grid. I use ajax for saving each item of this grid. as you can see in this image the user can click on save and this passes the row info by json to the action `createinvoiceitem` in the controller invoice.

I want the row of grid that was saved to change its color to green if the result of this safe was successful, otherwise I want this row to change its color to red, so the user knows which one was saved and which one aborted the save.

How can I know if this row was saved in the partial view? I used `view-bag` in my controller but I can't see `view bag` in the partial view, I used `session` but I can't see `session`.
[image]
This is function of save button in my partial view

```
function SaveRow(index) {
            alert($("#Invoice_InvoiceNumber").val());
            InvoiceItemValidation();
            var indexvalue1 = $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr td').filter(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text()) == index;
            }).parent().index();
            indexvalue = indexvalue1 + 1;
            var invoiceitem;        
            invoiceitem = ({

                InvoiceNumber: $("#Invoice_InvoiceNumber").val(),
                SparePartCode: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(2)').text(),
                Title: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(3)').text(),
                SerialNumber: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(4)').text(),
                Project: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(5) input[type=number]').val(),
                PartCount: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(6) input[type=number]').val(),
                Unit: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(7) input[type=text]').val(),
                Descr: $('#InvoiceItemGrid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + indexvalue + ') td:nth-child(8) input[type=text]').val(),
                FaultyReason: $('#FaultyResult').val(),
                ShamsiPickupDate: $('#date_input_PickupDate').val(),
                WagonNumber: $('#InvoiceItem_PartLocation1_WagonNumber').val(),
                Train: $('#TrainCode').val(),
                MasterApplier: $('#MasterApplier').val(),
                Troubleshooter: $('#Troubleshooter').val(),
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Invoice/InvoiceItemCreate',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(invoiceitem)
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                // Display the section contents.
                window.location.href = result.Url;
                alert('')
            });        
        }
```

This is the `createinvoice` action:

```
   public ActionResult InvoiceItemCreate(InvoiceItemModel invoiceitem)
    {
        ViewBag.Result ="true";            
        ViewBag.Aname = "PartialViewInvoiceItem";
        ViewBag.Cname = "Invoice";

        ViewBag.FaultyResult = _baseDataServise.GetList()
                                         .Where(u => u.BaseDataType1.Title == "نوع خرابی")
                                         .OrderBy(u => u.Title)
                                         .Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Title, Value = o.Id.ToString() })
                                         .AsEnumerable();


        ViewBag.Warehouses = _WarehouseService.GetList()
                                       .OrderBy(o => o.Title)
                                       .Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Title, Value = o.Id.ToString() })
                                       .AsEnumerable();

        DBResult _DBResult = _InvoiceItemService.AddInvoiceItem(invoiceitem);

        string ItemName = invoiceitem.InvoiceNumber+"_"+invoiceitem.SparePartCode;
        Session["ItemName"]=_DBResult.IsOK;
        return View("CreateFaultyInput",new InvoiceVM()); 

    }
```